# best way to delete element from array:javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found two ways. Which one is better? Is there any other way better than these two?

```
 myArray.splice($.inArray(id, myArray),1);
```

or

```
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(id),1);
```

Comment: `indexOf` might not work in some browsers. However, there is a hack for that in MDN. jQuery `inArray` method will work anyhow, but you need to use the library.

Comment: the indexOf method won't work on older browsers like IE 7/8 and $.inArray is a plain looping and hence works in every browser

Comment: @VisioN you should give your comment as answer, bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neither option is safe** because both will remove the last element from the array if `id` isn't found.

Whether you use `$.inArray()` or `.indexOf()` you'll get a return of `-1` if `id` isn't in the array, and when you pass `-1` to the [`.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it will remove the last item from the array.

So really you should say:

```
var index = $.inArray(id, myArray); // or myArray.indexOf(id)
if (index > -1) myArray.splice(index, 1);
```

Obviously you can encapsulate the above in a function of your own if desired.

As for which of `$.inArray()` and `.indexOf()` is better, that depends on whether you care about supporting older browsers (mainly IE8 and less) that don't support `.indexOf()`. You *should* care if your code is on a public website, since a lot of people still use IE8 and IE7. If you're already using jQuery you might as well stick with `$.inArray()`, otherwise use the [`.indexOf()` shim at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks bro. I will use $.inArray.                                        P.S : the function in which this code is called is only called when array has that element :-). So no need to check. but nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Empty the entire array:

```
while (myArray.length) {
  var element = myArray.shift();
  element = null; // free memory
}
myArray = [];
```

or delete single element:

```
var element = myArray.splice(id,1);
element = null; // free memory
```

Comment: Your `element = null` concept does _not_ free memory if the array element in question is an object referenced elsewhere, and if the array element is not referenced elsewhere how is your method better than just `myArray.shift()` or `myArray.splice()` on a line by itself?

Comment: The OP did not say that the element may be referenced elsewhere or that it may be an object. All the information we have is a single line question. A better written question would allow a better answer.

Comment: No fight, sorry for giving that impression, just a serious question that I would genuinely like a serious answer to: _why_ does your `element = null` thing free memory? Why would the memory not be freed by just `myArray.splice(id,1)` if you didn't use the `element` variable at all? Could you please explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following ways to delete element from array too.

```
var y = [1, 2, 3]
var removeItem = 2;

y = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});
```

OR

```
var arr = ["jQuery","JavaScript","HTML","Ajax","Css"];
var itemtoRemove = "HTML";
arr.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, arr),1);
```

Above both ways are best.

**Note:** IE < 9 does not support .indexOf() on arrays. If you want to make sure your code works in IE.

Comment: Your two methods don't have the same result as each other in the case where the item to be removed isn't found in the array, or in the case where there are other references to the original array.